# How to 'refresh token' using RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

I have a set of API calls written with Redux Toolkit. For example:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { Contacts } from '../datamodel/Contact';
import { getAccessToken } from '../util/userContextManagement';

export const contactsApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'contactsApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/api/users/current' }),
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getContacts: builder.query<Contacts, void>({
            query: () => {                
                return ({
                  url: '/contacts',
                  method: 'GET',
                  headers: { Authorization:  `Bearer ${getAccessToken()?.token}`}
                });
              },
        })
    })
})

export const { useGetContactsQuery } = contactsApi
```

I am able to inject the access token using a function: `getAccessToken()`.

However, I'd like to detect in the function that the access token has expired and refresh it with another API call before the function returns.

Unfortunately, I am not able to do this in this function, because `getAccessToken()` isn't react hook.

```
export const getAccessToken = () => {
    const [trigger] = useLazyGetRefreshTokensQuery();
    (...)
    return getUserContext().tokens.find(t => t.type === TokenTypeEnum.ACCESS_TOKEN)
}
```

I am getting:

```
React Hook "useLazyGetRefreshTokensQuery" is called in function "getAccessToken" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"
```

How could I refresh the token in RTK Query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I don't know if you can use any hook in your API. You might have to change the way to get the token by:

1. Have you tried renaming your custom hook with a `useGetAccessToken`? The error states `React Hook names must start with the word "use"`. This could fix the issue of retrieving the token.
2. Storing the token in the cookies - my favorite approach.
3. Passing the token as an argument directy from the state - however I've never done this though.

For refetching tokens,

You could try using the `baseQueryWithReauth` mentioned in the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery), where if the `token` returns `401` a call to your `refreshToken` method is made and you can store your updated tokens and retry the request.

It would look something like this in your implementation:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import type {
  BaseQueryFn,
  FetchArgs,
  FetchBaseQueryError,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import { Contacts } from "../datamodel/Contact";
import { getAccessToken } from "../util/userContextManagement";

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: '/api/users/current',
  prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
    // this method should retrieve the token without a hook
    const token = getAccessToken();

    if (token) {
      headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
    }
    return headers;
  },
});

const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);

  if (result.error && result.error.status === 401) {
    // try to get a new token
    const refreshResult = await baseQuery("/refreshToken", api, extraOptions);

    if (refreshResult.data) {
      // store the new token in the store or wherever you keep it
      api.dispatch(tokenReceived(refreshResult.data));
      // retry the initial query
      result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    } else {
      // refresh failed - do something like redirect to login or show a "retry" button
      api.dispatch(loggedOut());
    }
  }
  return result;
};

export const contactsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "contactsApi",
  baseQueryWithReauth,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getContacts: builder.query<Contacts, void>({
      query: () => {
        return {
          url: "/contacts",
          method: "GET",
        };
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetContactsQuery } = contactsApi;
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Using this with Typescript worked except `reducerPath` was erroring with "Type '"[reducerPath]"' is not assignable to type '"api"'." I fixed it by changing `baseQueryWithReauth` in createApi to be `baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth`.

Comment: How can we pass body in which we need to send refreshToken to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

I have adopted the following approach: in case of receiving a 401 status code, I send the refresh token in the body of a POST request. If I possess a refresh token, I include it in the POST request. However, I discovered that there is an option to send an argument as either a string or FetchArgs. The string example is widely available, even in the documentation of reauthentication (reauth) for RTKQuery. However, FetchArgs allow users to send a POST request along with the refreshToken as a body parameter.

```
    import {
  FetchArgs,
  FetchBaseQueryError,
  FetchBaseQueryMeta,
  // BaseQueryFn,
  createApi,
  fetchBaseQuery,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import {RootState} from './store';
import {BASE_URL} from '@env';

import {MaybePromise} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/tsHelpers';
import {
  BaseQueryFn,
  QueryReturnValue,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/baseQueryTypes';
import {logout, setAuthenticated} from '../domains/auth/slices';

const baseApi = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: BASE_URL,
  credentials: 'include',

  prepareHeaders: (headers, {getState}) => {
    const {token} = (getState() as RootState).persistedReducer.loginSlice;
    if (token) {
      headers.set('Authorization', `${token}`);
    }
    return headers;
  },
});

const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result: MaybePromise<
    QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta>
  > = await baseApi(args, api, extraOptions);

  const refreshToken = (api.getState() as RootState)?.persistedReducer
    .loginSlice?.refreshToken;
  if ((result?.error as any)?.originalStatus === 401) {
    const refreshResult = await baseApi(
      {
        url: '/customer/refresh-token',
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({refreshToken}),
      },
      {...api},
      extraOptions,
    );
    console.log(refreshResult, 'Save Innocent Lives Stop war Save Gaza Say Yes to peace and No to war');
    if (refreshResult.data) {
      api?.dispatch(
        setAuthenticated({
          ...refreshResult?.data,
          isAuthenticated: true,
        }),
      );

  result = await baseApi(args, api, extraOptions);
    } else {
       api.dispatch(logout());
    }
  }
  return result;
};

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  endpoints: () => ({}),
  refetchOnReconnect: true,
});
```